# Python: Object custom property glitch

Tags: python

I have the following custom prop:

```
class Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    enabled = False 
    state = {
        "some_data": None, # edit: this points to numpy array
        "some_other_data": None
    }        
    string_prop = StringProperty(
        name='Heyyy')
```

Assigned to:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_settings = PointerProperty(type=Settings)
```

There are two issues I am having.

1) I cannot change the value of `enabled`, like so:

```
class Init(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.init"
    bl_label = "Init"
    def execute(self, context):
        context.object.my_settings.enabled = True
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

2) All of the objects share and control values of `state`

There are no issues with blender props like the `string_prop` above.

I assume this is just how Blender handles custom PropertyGroups. Is there a way to make this work? I need to have information stored per object. The only other solution I can think of so far is to store an array of custom props per scene and check which one is currently active based on the id of the selected object, but that is more complicated than I would like it to be.

Comment: The issue as I see it is in storing your custom data.  Your enabled property above is a class property.  bpy.props.stringproperty is used to add a property of that type on each instance.  See [docs on property getter setter](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#get-set-example) which shows how the properties are stored  using custom properties of the same name.  You can also use the ol' fashioned python `property(getter, setter)`  and a global (if you don't need to save) or could save to a string json style etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean flag is the simple part here. As you already assumed, those `PropertyGroups` are designed to hold Blender Properties only. So instead of

```
enabled = False
```

you should use

```
enabled = BoolProperty(default = False)  // which is anyways the default
```

The state property is more difficult. There are no Dictionary properties available to you, but maybe you can work around your issue by using a `CollectionProperty` instead?

Create a class first to hold your collection, for example:

```
class MyCollection(PropertyGroup):
    val1 = StringProperty()
    val2 = IntProperty(min = 0, max = 999)
    // etc etc
```

Then, in your `Settings` class, reference it like this:

```
variableCollection = CollectionProperty(type = MyCollection)
```

To add items to the collection, use this in your operator code:

```
x = context.object.my_settings.variableCollection.add()
x.val1 = 'This works'
x.val2 = 34
```

Alternatively, you can also nest PropertyGroups of course. That would be

```
nestedProperties = PointerProperty(type = MyCollection)
```

That would allow you to do:

```
context.object.my_settings.nestedProperties.val1 = 'This is nested'
context.object.my_settings.nestedProperties.val2 = 33
```

It depends on your situation in terms of what works best. But keep in mind that Blender's own property types are the only ones it can store with the file.

One last way to store Python data - but this does not save that data with the file - is simply using a key - value approach on the object. You can always use something like:

```
x = bpy.context.object
x['myCustomKey'] = myDesiredValue
```

The resulting data can then even be viewed in the viewport:

[image]

Comment: thanks for a great answer! Unfortunately I am storing numpy arrays and lists in the `state` dic..

Comment: @VSB Maybe you should use a different approach then: try `x = context.object` followed by `x['myCustomData'] = whateverYouNeed`. This can hold arrays, lists, whatnot, and is attatched to the object in question. Unfortunately, you cannot save the results this way in the file.

Comment: haha that I think should work perfectly, thanks!!

Comment: looks like we almost had it.. for some reason Blender converts numpy arrays stored per object to IDPropertyArray :(

Comment: @VSB maybe Richard Colburn can help? He did a few numpy for Blender Tutorials here https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCavaCSVksKt6RvrBmohmSoA

Comment: it looks like Blender just does not allow anything other than the standard data types. I will have to use another way or just go back to having settings per scene. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯